# No quiere eliminar el boton en la tabla LocalStorage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, crud, local-storage

ando realizando un proyecto y necesito almacenar unas variables temporalmente en el navegador sin la necesidad de utilizar base de datos. Entonces encontre en popular LocalStorage en js, utilice un source que esta en internet y le hice una modificaciones, para que cuando agregue las variables se reflejen en una Tabla junto con el Boton de eliminar, pero cuando coloco el boton en una tabla no quiere eliminar.

```js
 var showAll = function () {
        localStorageCRUD.readAll(function(lists) {
          console.log(lists);
          var html = '';
          lists.forEach(function (d) {
            html +='<tr id="' + d.id + '">' +
                   '<td>' + d.name + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + d.data + '</td>' +
                   '<td><button class="btn btn-danger delete">Quitar</button></td>' +
                   '</tr>';
          });
          $('.lists').html(html);
        });
      };
      showAll();

      // bind events
      // add
      $('button.add').click(function () {
        var $new = $('.new');
        var name = $new.find('.name').val().trim();
        var data = $new.find('.data').val().trim();
        if (!name && !data) {
          return;
        }
        localStorageCRUD.create({
          name: name,
          data: data
        }, function (d) {
          showAll();
        });
      });
      // delete
      $('.lists').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        var id = $(this).closest('p').data('id');
        localStorageCRUD.delete({
          id: id
        }, function (d) {
          showAll();
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/jdk137/crud_localStorage/blob/master/crud.js"></script>

<div class="new">
      <input class="name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $url; ?>"/>
      <input class="data" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $horanueva; ?>"/>
      
      <button class="btn btn-success add">Guardar</button>

    </div>

 <h3>URLs: <?php echo $url; ?></h3>
 
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>URL</th>
    <th>Tiempo</th>
    <th>Eliminar</th>
  </tr> 
    <tbody class="lists">
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserte éste bloque

```
$('.lists').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        var id = $(this).closest('p').data('id');
        localStorageCRUD.delete({
          id: id
        }, function (d) {
          showAll();
        });
      });
```

dentro de la función showAll() pero al final, de ésta manera el evento onclick dinámico se activara exactamente después de la agregación de filas.